# Create a json object in Rails app for d3.js but depending on the paginating

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, d3.js

I want to include my working d3.js code to my Rails app. In my view for builds I'm using paginating because there are about 30000 lines. I want to visualize them with d3.js.

It is working for the first 100 lines when I just call a json-object via the model name:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
d3.json('builds', 
            function(data){
                //working function code..
            });     
<% end %>
```

But the json-object `builds` takes everytime the first 100 items independent from the paginating. That means `builds` has all data but it just takes the first 100 because I say in builds model `self.per_page = 100` that I can use that for my paginating.

I also tried to create a json-object in the view that just has the current build-objects:

```
var myJson = <%=raw @builds.to_json %>;
```

But the problem here is that I can't give the d3.json function a variable name.

Does anyone know how I can create a json object that I can use for my d3 code that is depending on the current page?

I hope it is clear what I mean otherwise please ask!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after trying everything I found out how this works:

```
d3.json('<% @builds.to_json %>', 
            function(data){
          //code
```

You cannot create a variable and pass it into the d3.json function but you have to let it evaluate the ruby code by itself.